# How to know when an Android fragment is being closed?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `Timer` running in my `Fragment` and I'd like to stop this timer when the `Fragment` is being dismissed. I cannot find any reasonable method to override to get a notification when the fragment is being popped off the back stack or another fragment is pushed over it.

Is there some way to find out that the fragment is going 'off screen'?

Comment: onDestroy isn't sufficient ?

Comment: Or `onDetach()`, or `onPause()`, depending upon what you mean by "going 'off screen'"?

Answer (score 0):

try this one inside the fragment class:

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) { }
        else {  }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just override the onStop() method.

```
@Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();


        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fragment stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```